# How to modify only one dataframe table in html?

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

I have Html local site which includes two DataFrame, I need both to look different. I could use CSS or classes  to format only one table but I don't know how to use it on a DataFrame object.

Right now my code looks something like this:

```
html = f'''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="pl">
<head>
   <title>some title</title>
</head>
<style>
table {{
        width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-left: 30px;
     }}
                            
     table td, table th {{
        border: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
        padding: 5px 15px;

     }}
     tablek tbody td {{
        font-size: 13px;
     }}
     table thead th {{
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: left;
     }}
     table tfoot td {{
        font-size: 14px;
     }}
</style>
<body>
   some text.......
   {DF.to_html()}
   some text.......
   {DF2.to_html()}
</body>
</html>
'''
```

This formatting for a table using styles works fine but formats all tables. I need the other one to look different. How to do this? Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
<div id="div1">{df.to_html}</div>
<div id="div2">{df2.to_html}</div>
```

and use these selectors

```
#div1 table
#div2 table
```